# get gender with apple login

Tags: ios, swift, flutter

I am trying to get the gender with apple login but it doesn't have the scope. defined in the same documentation, but I try to upload my application and they reject it because they say that it makes no sense to ask them for the gender in the registration form if I already have it with the apple login, but in the documentation, there is nothing on how to obtain gender.

I'm working with flutter, I don't know if this can be obtained with native, can you answer me?

`Apple Docs:` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices/asauthorization/scope

Comment: If apple login is the same as Apple ID then I agree that gender is not an existing property. _” they reject it because they say”_, maybe the best thing is to get back to “they” and ask for clarification.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson yes, i will do that. I really don't see the point of it because they reject the app when they don't even provide a solution in the documentation. Do you know by chance if natively in ios you can get more than just the email and name?

Comment: looks like you can't https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices/asauthorization/scope

Answer (score 0):

No. The supported scopes are email and name.

Comment: this is rather a comment than an answer

Comment: @HeshanSandeepa "It's not possible" with an explanation is absolutely an answer.